# Images centered inside a Div with CSS

Tags: css, css-float

Hi have a div that's wrapping images..The width of this DIV can change so I've set it to 100%

```
<div id="wrapperDiv"></div>
```

Inside I have images/thumbnails floated to the left with a margin or the right and bottom of the image.

```
margin:0 10px 10px auto;
```

Depending on the window of the wrapper div sometimes I fit 10 thumbnail images per row and sometimes less.

I need the images to be centered so that the space in the left and right is the same.

Have can I do this with CSS?

Comment: Good examples which might help: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: Try wrapping them in another div with `display: inline-block` and set the wrapper to `text-align: center`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try adding an extra wrapper-div, with following CSS:

```
wrapper-inside {
    margin:0 10%;
    width:90%;
}
```

Or even easier (without extra div):

```
wrapperDiv {
    padding:0 10%;
}
```

EDIT:

I was thinking about this on my way to the supermarket, and realized this doesn't perfectly center the images - Viruzzo's suggestion is the only one that works:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    div.wrapper {
        text-align:center;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <img width="200" height="120">
            <img width="200" height="120">
            <img width="200" height="120">
            <img width="200" height="120">
            <img width="200" height="120">
            <img width="200" height="120">
            <img width="200" height="120">
            <img width="200" height="120">
            <img width="200" height="120">
            <img width="200" height="120">
            <img width="200" height="120">
            <img width="200" height="120">
            <img width="200" height="120">
            <img width="200" height="120">
            <img width="200" height="120">
            <img width="200" height="120">
            <img width="200" height="120">
            <img width="200" height="120">
            <img width="200" height="120">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/centered.html

Tim

Comment: can we post answers instead of links, then what is the difference between google and stackoverflow

Comment: 9.9 times of out 10 I post answers, not links.  In this case however the answer is involved, I knew where to look, and credit should go where it's due.